# VS2015 + Nuget + WebAPI2 (Incorrect System.Web.Http Reference)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2, nuget-package-restore

I have several projects that have Nuget references to Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (each of my REST services is a separate project). Now this all works swimmingly if just created and built. However when someone pulls this solution from our source control, they obviously don't get any Nuget packages, binaries, or object folders. And here in is where the problem lies...

When a clean solution is provided, the reference to System.Web.Http.dll (from Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core) is incorrect. Seems like Visual Studio is just ignoring what was previously referenced and searching for a replacement. Every project that expects this assembly would normally be pointed to the one pulled in by Nuget. But instead they all point to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Http.dll
```

As such, if the Nuget packages are restored, this assembly is left untouched, and therefore breaks the builds. Looking into the project files I find:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\lib\nuget\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

which is 100% correct, that is the assembly I want. So why am I not getting it? or maybe a better question is, why is Nuget not replacing the incorrect reference with the correct one during restore?

Comment: I changed <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion> to <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion> on all my projects, which seems to fix the broken builds, but it still doesn't explain why this breaks in the first place.

Comment: Any chance you have a binding redirect anywhere in your app.config?

Comment: No, these are all strictly class library projects, so there are no app.config files. And the nuget packages.config for each of them are correct:
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <packages>
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
      <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
      <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net46" />
    </packages>`